# How to handle sequence file in spark-sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data sample :

file name: sample.txt

```
| TRANSACTION_ID | ITEM_ID      | AUC_END_DT | BD_ID     | BD_SITE |
+----------------+--------------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 320562466      | 7322548247   | 5/22/2005  | 32148826  | 77      |
| 569643695009   | 190558793670 | 7/31/2011  | 112644812 | 0       |
```

Here is the query that I'm running :

```sql
select * from table_name where item_id = '$item_id';
```

I need to convert this `sample.txt` file into sequence file  and then  need to create `DataFrame` for that sequence file for further analysis.

```scala
case class db_col(  transaction_id:Double,
            item_id:Long,    
            auc_end_dt:String,
            bd_id:Long,
            bd_site:Int)

object V_bd {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val item_id_args = args(0)

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("POC_Naren").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ssc = new SQLContext(sc)

    import ssc.implicits._

    val dw_bid_base_rdd = sc.textFile("C:/Users/Downloads/sqlscript/reference/data/sample.txt")    

    val bd_trans_rdd = dw_bid_base_rdd.map(row => row.split("\\|"))
    val bd_col_rdd = bd_trans_rdd.map(p =>   db_col(p(0).trim.toDouble,p(1),p(2),p(.3).trim.tolong,p(4).trim.toInt))
    val bd_df_rdd = bd_col_rdd.toDF()
    bd_df_rdd.registerTempTable("bd_table")

     val bd_table_query = ssc.sql("select * from table_name where item_id = '$item_id_args';")
     bd_table_query.show()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to convert your DataFrame into a RDD[(K,V)]. Example

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, DataFrame}

val bd_table_query : DataFrame = ???

val rdd : RDD[(Int,String)] = df.rdd.map {
  case r : Row => (r.getAs[Int](0),r.getAs[String](1)) // I'll let you choose your keys and convert into the right format
}
```

Then you can save the RDD :

```
rdd.saveAsSequenceFile("output.seq")
```